# copy and paste data frame from R into EXCEL

Tags: r, excel

I am using windows 10 on a DELL laptop. I previously could use the shortcut copy option (Ctrl + C) to copy data frame directly into excel from R using the paste option (Ctrl + V). However, upon a recent trial, the data does not show up in excel. This is not the case when I copy a text from R studio and paste it in either excel or word.
What could be accounting for this?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to save the data frame as a CSV file?

```
write.csv(df, file="df.csv")
```

Which saves to your directory.